# MVC correct handling of ajax search form and paging

Tags: ajax, view, controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a question regarding the ajax and simple filtering. Before writing this  post i did read some question more or less regarding this topic, but it is not the same and i didn't receive my answere there!

I have a simple search page, with only few filtering, this filtering should not immidiately be adjustaed to the results or whatever. So when the user changes the filters and click search he gets the result, when he modifies filter nothing should happen until he clicks search again.

So my question is more about handling with the paging, i know how the paging works on the server side with .Skip() .Take() however when i click on the page number, i still have to do an ajax call and submit the same model back just with other page number, but the paging is outside of the form and it doesn't have submit stuff on it ... so how do i resubmit the model back with all the filteres in there?

So here is my view:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Search", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "searchResults" }, new { @role = "form", @class = "form-horizontal" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
                 @Html.EditorFor(m => m.IsOnline)

                 @Html.EditorFor(m => m.UserLocation)
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">@Base.Search</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
```

And the paging is:

```
@if(Model.TotalPages>1)
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-centered">
            <ul class="pagination text-center">
                <li class="disabled"><a href="#">&laquo;</a></li>
                @{
                    for(int i = 1; i<=Model.TotalPages; i++)
                    {
                        <li><a href="#">@i 
                            @if(Model.CurrentPage==i)
                            {
                                <span class='sr-only'>(current)</span>
                            }
                        </a></li>
                    }    

                }
                <li><a href="#">&raquo;</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

And here is my controller:

```
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(SearchModel searchModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            searchModel = Operations.GetSearchedListUsers(searchModel);
        }

        return View(searchModel);
    }
```

So how i see it, even when i click on the page number i should do an index post action and re submit model but for example with other pagenumber how should i do it?

Or is my thinking is totaly wrong and in first place i shouldn't use ajax.form and model??

Please give advice?

Comment: have you  tried ajax.Post and ajax.Get?

Comment: Yes i did, but not in very advanced way, just some button when you click and that is it ... but here it is a bit different i think ... and yeah i would like to hear advice from experts

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Lets start with a general search page.

In search page we will a SearchPage view which have partial view SearchResult view which also may have another paging controls

1. SearchPage view will have all the control Filter that will keep the states if search, searchResult view update when Search Button is click. To maintain the filter,search keyword and page number and other states we would need to override the default submit and handle all through the ajax calls.
2. SearchResult view is partial view which will be updated on the searchbutton or Page click.
3. We might need to create searchModel model that has all the requires attributes:Filters,keyword and Page.
4. To make everything in ease, we would handle all these secenario in a single action called 
   Search with SearchModel. The searchModel will return a partialView("SearchResult").

Regarding the ajax call, lets say we have

```
  var keyword=$("#txtKeyword").val();
  var filter1=$("#txtFilter11").val();
  function SubmitSearch() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/Search',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { keyword: keyword, Filter1: filter1}
            timeout: 50000,
            success: function (data) {
                //Process data
                                },
            error: function (x, t, m) {
                if (t === "timeout") {
                    alert("got timeout");
                } else {
                    alert(t);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

And you can hook in the search button, page button etc.

Comment: Adding this function will automatically override the submit behabiour of submit button?

Comment: And how do i add partial view to a correct place on my view? I specified: UpdateTargetId = "searchResult" but it still renders the partial view for full page :/

Comment: no, you need to use preventdefault or return false.

Comment: suppose you have a SearchResultContainer Div, then you can update the ajax call
`success: function (data) {
                
$("#SearchResultContainer").html(data);
                                }`

Comment: ah so ok ... by return false you mean i should put it in submitsearch function? but what if the button is of type submit how do you know that this function will be called, or maybe i should not make it type of submit?

Comment: you can override the submit button in the same fashion on onclick event .